# A doubt regarding the extended form of the Weierstrass factorization theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, factorization

I want to represent $\sin(x)-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ as a product of it's zeroes

According to the Weierstrass factorization theorem, the sine function can be represented as a product of its factors:

$$\sin(x)-0=(x) \left(1 - \frac{x}{\pi} \right) \left(1 + \frac{x}{\pi} \right) \left(1 -  \frac{x}{2\pi} \right) \left(1 + \frac{x}{2\pi} \right) \left(1 - \frac{x}{3\pi} \right) \left(1 + \frac{x}{3\pi} \right) \cdots$$

Following this method, is it valid to represent $$\sin(x)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}) \left(1 - \frac{4x}{\pi} \right) \left(1 - \frac{4x}{3\pi} \right) \left(1 +  \frac{4x}{5\pi} \right) \left(1 + \frac{4x}{7\pi} \right) \cdots??$$

(Since, the factors of $\sin(x)-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ are: $\dfrac{\pi}{4},\dfrac{3\pi}{4},\dfrac{-5\pi}{4},\dfrac{-7\pi}{4},\cdots$)

I would also like to know the general Weierstrass factorizations of $\sin(x)-k$

Comment: Note that this product is not absolutely convergent, so you need to excercise some care here with the ordering, but it should be true.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I can't find any online resources that go in depth about the Weierstrass factorisation theorem. I just have a basic understanding of the concepts. One interesting thing I found about this factorisation involves differentiating it and slightly manipulating the value to get the Dirichlet L-series. And again I can't find any good online resources about the derivation of Dirichlet L-series so I don't know if what I found is new or not :)

Comment: You are jumping a bit too fast from the general Weierstrass factorization theorem to L-functions. For the former (and in general, for the basic theory of entire functions) my go-to reference is the book "Lectures on entire functions" by Boris Yakovlevich Levin. Dirichlet L-functions are functions of finite order (in fact, of order $1$), so you should be able to apply Hadamard factorization theorem from that book.

Comment: But remember please that MO is a Q&A site so be a bit more concise with what you are asking. If you want the proof of the (suitably reguralized) equality for $\sin(x) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ I can provided it later today, but if you want something more general please specify exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you I would greatly appreciate a proof

Comment: Since this function is of exponential type, a better framework is Hadamard factorization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_factorization_theorem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For any complex $k$, let $u$ be any complex solution of the equation $\sin u=k$ (such a solution of course exists). Using now the identity
$$\sin x=x\prod_{k=1}^\infty\Big(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2}\Big),$$
we get
$$\sin x-k=\sin x-\sin u
=2\sin\frac{x-u}2\cos\frac{x+u}2
=2\sin\frac{x-u}2\sin\frac{\pi-x-u}2
=\frac{(x-u)(\pi-x-u)}2\, 
\prod_{k=1}^\infty\Big(1-\frac{(x-u)^2}{4k^2\pi^2}\Big)
\Big(1-\frac{(\pi-x-u)^2}{4k^2\pi^2}\Big)$$
for all complex $x$.

Comment: Thank you. Just one follow up question, why is it that my initial factorisation of $\sin(x)-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ provides true results if it is wrong?

Comment: The "true" results here being the Dirichlet L-series(upon differentiating) and an infinite product when x is replaced by something like $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$...

Comment: @Lithium : I don't know how your result for $\sin(x)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ was obtained.

Comment: Since the roots of $\sin(x)-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ are $\dfrac{\pi}{4},\dfrac{3\pi}{4},\cdots$, I naively constructed a product with each term being of the form:$1-\dfrac{x}{X_{root}}$ with an additional $\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$ to equate the values at $x=0$

Comment: @Lithium : According to Mathematica, your product is representation of $\sin x-1/\sqrt2$ is correct. It can also be obtained, after some rearrangements, from the answer above with $u=\pi/4$ (say) and the product representation of $\sin$.

Answer (score 1):

Although Iosif Pinelis already gave a slick answer, let me indicate an approach based on a more general theory of entire functions, though I will omit some details to not turn this answer into a literal chapter of some book.

We have two functions. On the one hand, we have a function $f(z) =\sin(z) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. On the other hand, we have

$$g(z) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\prod_{n = 1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{z}{\lambda_n}\right)\left(1+\frac{z}{\mu_n}\right),$$
where $\lambda_n$ are positive roots of $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $-\mu_n$ are negative roots of the same equation, both in increasing order. It is not hard to see that $\lambda_n = \pi n + O(1), \mu_n = \pi n + O(1)$. From this, in particular, we can deduce that above product converges absolutely for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$. Moreover, you can (with some work, but nothing hard, just bounding each term in a basic way) show that $g(z)$ is of order $1$, that is $|g(z)| \le C_\varepsilon e^{|z|^{1+\varepsilon}}$ (I believe, with slightly more work you can even show that we can take $\varepsilon = 0$ here).

Now, let us consider the ratio $h(z) = \frac{g(z)}{f(z)}$. Observe that this function is entire and has no zeroes, since all the zeroes of $g$ and $f$ are simple and exactly cancel. Moreover, $f(z)$ is also of order $1$. From the general theory we know that if $g$ and $f$ are of  order (at most) $\kappa$ and $\frac{g}{f}$ turns out to be entire, then it is also of order (at most) $\kappa$. Thus, $h$ is of order at most $1$ (recall that our goal is to show that $h(z) \equiv 1$). Moreover, $h$ has no zeroes. Thus (again, from some very general theory), it must have the form $e^{az+b}$. Since $h(0) = 0$, we have $b = 0$.

It remains to show that $a = 0$. Classical way to show this is to study the asymptotics of $h(z)$ as $z = x, x\in \mathbb{R}, x\to \pm \infty$ and $z = iy, y\in \mathbb{R}, y\to \pm \infty$. I will spare us from the second point with the following cheat: observe that obviously $h(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ if $x\in \mathbb{R}$, thus $a\in \mathbb{R}$ (however, if say we considered $\sin(x) - k$, $k\notin \mathbb{R}$ then we would have to do it, though proving essential boundedness of $h$ on $i\mathbb{R}$ is easier than on $\mathbb{R}$).

It is enough to show that, say, $g(z)$ is bounded by some polynomial on $\mathbb{R}$, because then if $a > 0$ we get contradiction for big enough positive $x$, while if $a < 0$ we get a contradiction for big enough negative $x$.

So, let us pick some $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (for brevity, I will only consider $x > 0$) and we want to bound $g(x)$. We will split the product into three groups: first group is $\pi n < x - C$, second group is $x - C \le \pi n \le x + C$ and the third group is $\pi n > x + C$, where $C$ is big enough ($C > 4\pi$ would be enough). The second group in the product will give us $O(1)$, so we will ignore it. We are going compare the remaining product with the product for $\sin(x)$ (let me assume that $x$ is not close to the zero of a sine, otherwise we will just throw away the term giving us near $0$ value).

In the first group we always have $\left|1-\frac{x}{\lambda_n}\right| = \frac{x}{\lambda_n}-1$, let us pair this with the term in the product for sine with slightly smaller root, then the term in the sine product will be bigger. Similarly, $\left|1+\frac{x}{\mu_m}\right| = \frac{x}{\lambda_n}+1$ and we do the same here. Finally, we do the same for the last group.

It remains to notice that since $\lambda_n, \mu_n = \pi n + O(1)$, we can do this for all but (possibly) finitely many terms of our product, and similarly we will omit at most finitely many terms in the product for sine. The total product of this finite number of terms is itself bounded by a polynomial. Thus (up to throwing away that term if we are near the zero of a sine), we essentially got that $|g(x)|\le P(x)|\sin (x)|\le P(x)$, thus $g$ is polynomially bounded.

In the general setting such pairing will not work, but under some (fairly mild) conditions you can still bound the product, by taking the logarithm essentially, since all we need to get is that this product grows slower than any exponential. And on the imaginary axis everything is even simpler as I said above, just bounding each term in the most basic way will give you that the function $g$ grows at most like a $P(y)e^{|y|}$.

Comment: Very rigorous approach I must admit it's a bit too advanced for me though :) Correct me if I'm wrong but from what I understood, you essentially proved that my factorisation of the function as a product of the coefficient k and the zeroes of the function is correct but the final factorisation might not be equal to what I claimed??

Comment: @Lithium What I'm essentially trying to say is that the product is correct, but you have to be careful while ordering the zeroes. For example, ordering them in increasing absolute value works.